# R - filter is giving error "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1"

Tags: r, filter

I am using csv files from this data set https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html
I unzipped on put the files in to a directory of just the csv files so I can read them in.

```
    df<- list.files(path="/Users/race/developer/csv/", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
      lapply(read_csv) %>% 
      bind_rows 
    df
```

some of the rows are missing start_lat data which renders the distance calculations to be off by thousands of miles.

I am trying to filter out the rows with missing GPS coordinates

```
    df_clean_distances <- filter( df, df$start_station_name == "")
    df_clean_distances
```

but I get this
" Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1" when I try the code above

```
    df_clean_distances <- dplyr::filter( df, start_station_name == "")
    dput( head (df_clean_distances ))

structure(list(ride_id = character(0), rideable_type = character(0), 
    started_at = structure(numeric(0), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), ended_at = structure(numeric(0), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), start_station_name = character(0), start_station_id = character(0), 
    end_station_name = character(0), end_station_id = character(0), 
    start_lat = numeric(0), start_lng = numeric(0), end_lat = numeric(0), 
    end_lng = numeric(0), member_casual = character(0), duration_secs = structure(numeric(0), class = "difftime", units = "secs"), 
    distance_miles = numeric(0), speed_mph = numeric(0), duration_hrs = numeric(0)), row.names = integer(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")
```

Comment: Make sure to use the namespace ``dplyr`` as in ``dplyr::filter`` since the ``filter`` function can collide with ``stats::filter`` and give weird errors. You don't need to have ``df$`` in the second argument of ``filter`` - ``dplyr::filter(df, start_station_name == "")`` will do.

Comment: Also please add in the output of ``dput(head(df_clean_distances))`` to your question. Thanks.

Comment: added the code you asked for

Comment: so something is wrong in my filter() call.

Comment: Apologies, I meant the output of ``dput(head(df))``.

Comment: so something is wrong in my filter() call. the original data from, df, has three million rows. But when I apply the filter I thought filter() returned all the rows that met the condition. I know there are start_station_names that are blank because I can see them excel, I guess I need to look at the raw cvs as it does not seem to be detecting the value as blank, NA or NULL. Or perhaps I did something else to clear out the blanks prior.

Comment: Oh, if you want to filter out those rows then you need to do ``dplyr::filter( df, start_station_name != "")``.

Comment: I did the dput(head(df)) and it show the 3 million records, I guess on of my previous filters took out the bad row already, but I am not sure how I did that. will restructure and rewrite. So new to all this

Comment: Not sure what I did exactly but it is working now, thank you for the help, I learned about dput()